# Scrapy parse_item callback not being called

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm having a problem getting my Scrapy spider to run its callback method.

I don't think it's an indentation error which seems to be the case for the other previous posts, but perhaps it is and I don't know it? Any ideas?

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy import log
import tldextract

class CrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = "crawler"

  def __init__(self, initial_url):
    log.msg('initing...', level=log.WARNING)
    CrawlSpider.__init__(self)

    if not initial_url.startswith('http'):
      initial_url = 'http://' + initial_url

    ext = tldextract.extract(initial_url)
    initial_domain = ext.domain + '.' + ext.tld
    initial_subdomain = ext.subdomain + '.' + ext.domain + '.' + ext.tld
    self.allowed_domains = [initial_domain, 'www.' + initial_domain, initial_subdomain]
    self.start_urls = [initial_url]
    self.rules = [
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item'),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow_domains=self.allowed_domains), follow=True),
    ]
    self._compile_rules()

  def parse_item(self, response):
    log.msg('parse_item...', level=log.WARNING)
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    links = hxs.select("//a/@href").extract()
    for link in links:
      log.msg('link', level=log.WARNING)
```

Sample output is below; it should show a warning message with "parse_item..." printed but it doesn't.

```
$ scrapy crawl crawler -a initial_url=http://www.szuhanchang.com/test.html
2013-02-19 18:03:24+0000 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.16.4 started (bot: crawler)
2013-02-19 18:03:24+0000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2013-02-19 18:03:24+0000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2013-02-19 18:03:24+0000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2013-02-19 18:03:24+0000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2013-02-19 18:03:24+0000 [scrapy] WARNING: initing...
2013-02-19 18:03:24+0000 [crawler] INFO: Spider opened
2013-02-19 18:03:24+0000 [crawler] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2013-02-19 18:03:24+0000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2013-02-19 18:03:24+0000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2013-02-19 18:03:25+0000 [crawler] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.szuhanchang.com/test.html> (referer: None)
2013-02-19 18:03:25+0000 [crawler] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.20130219-0606.com': <GET http://www.20130219-0606.com/>
2013-02-19 18:03:25+0000 [crawler] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2013-02-19 18:03:25+0000 [crawler] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
        {'downloader/request_bytes': 234,
         'downloader/request_count': 1,
         'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
         'downloader/response_bytes': 363,
         'downloader/response_count': 1,
         'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
         'finish_reason': 'finished',
         'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 19, 18, 3, 25, 84855),
         'log_count/DEBUG': 8,
         'log_count/INFO': 4,
         'log_count/WARNING': 1,
         'request_depth_max': 1,
         'response_received_count': 1,
         'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
         'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
         'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
         'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
         'start_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 19, 18, 3, 24, 805064)}
2013-02-19 18:03:25+0000 [crawler] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you running this spider?  From the command line with `scrapy crawl crawler`?

Comment: Through a sidekiq (queuing) worker, but I've tried it on the commandline as well with no luck. I've changed the question to include the commandline output for better clarity.

Comment: Please provide a short, self-contained example (http://sscce.org/). If I pasted this code into a new spider, it wouldn't work plus I'd have to install the tldextract module, which makes testing a little tricky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `start_urls` of http://www.szuhanchang.com/test.html has only one anchor link, namely:

```
<a href="http://www.20130219-0606.com">Test</a>
```

which contains a link to the domain `20130219-0606.com` and according to your `allowed_domains` of:

```
['szuhanchang.com', 'www.szuhanchang.com', 'www.szuhanchang.com']
```

this Request gets filtered by the `OffsiteMiddleware`:

```
2013-02-19 18:03:25+0000 [crawler] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.20130219-0606.com': <GET http://www.20130219-0606.com/>
```

therefore `parse_item` will not be called for this url.

Comment: I have two rules though, one rule contains the allowed domains and should not follow offsite URLs, and the other says to run the callback on every URL found.

Comment: The second rule will never be processed because a link will only be processed once, by the first rule that it satisfies, and the first rule is satisfied by all links (by default the href in an anchor tag).  And another thing is that the link extractor will pull out links according to its parameters, in your case, the `allow_domains` argument, (if say this rule were first) but this list of links does not override the `OffsiteMiddleware` and in this case, it is filtered out.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the name of your callback to `parse_start_url` seems to work, although since the test URL provided is quite small, I cannot be sure if this will still be effective. Give it a go and let me know. :)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work; it would be weird if it did, since 'parse_item' isn't an implemented method in any of the Crawler parent classes and many examples online use that exact callback method name.

Comment: It works on mine, but then I had to hardcode `initial_domain` and `initial_subdomain` to remove the `tldextract` references so it's not the same as the code above. If you could post a non-working example without using that module, then that would be better.